# How to map a year to an integer?

Tags: c#, postgresql, mapping

I whish I could map a year extracted from a date in a postgresql database to a C# int.

```
select extract(year from current_date) "Year";
```

I get the following error: `Can't cast database type float8 to Int32`.

How could I retrieve the year as an int as it should naturally do?

Comment: Did you get this error on the C# code or directly from the query?

Comment: @Steve I get the error on C# side at mapping time

Comment: The documentation does state _"The extract function returns values of type double precision"_ https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

Comment: @PaulF I understand the `extract` function returns a double, but the question is how to retrieve an int for mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the value in the request :

```
select extract(year from current_date)::integer "Year";
```

Comment: why you cast to numeric first?

Comment: Indeed @PMerlet, `select extract(year from current_date)::integer "Year";` seems to work too, is there a reason to cast `numeric` first?

Comment: No reason, that was a mistake. I update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

according to postgresql [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) extract return double precision not integer

```
extract(field from timestamp)   double precision
```

You either:

- cast the extract result to integer as PMerlet answer
- assign the result to a double in c#
- do the casting to integer in c#

.

```
int someInt = (int)someDouble;
```

Comment: I understand `extract(field from timestamp)` returns a double, the question is how to retrieve an int for mapping, not how to do a cast

Comment: Your question seems to imply that you expected an int to be returned rather than a double. The result of the extract function needs converting (casting) to an integer at some point, so you do need to know how to do a cast - you need to ask your question clearly. This answer gives you three options that would work so does not deserve a downvote. There is a fourth option which is more consistent with standard SQL - _select CAST(extract(year from current_date) AS integer) "Year";_ https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS